# Pinescript week starting from Friday to Thursday

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I have a script where it plots weekly high horizontal line

```
//@version=4
study("VHCPRWM", overlay=true, precision=1)
plotWH=input(title = "Plot Weekly High & Low?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
weekH = security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(plotWH ? weekH : na, title = "Weekly High" , color = weekHLColor, style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth =2)
```

Here the week is considered from Monday to Sunday.
I would like the scriptto consider the beginning of week as Friday and ends with Thursday.
So basically I want to plot a weekly high line consideringthe week starting with friday and ending with thursday.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting weekly high you can fetch daily high from request.security  function. And keep calculating highest of daily highs from friday to thursday and then save it in a variable which can be plotted for next week. Example below

```
//@version=4
study("VHCPRWM", overlay=true, precision=1)
weekHLColor=color.blue
plotWH=input(title = "Plot Weekly High & Low?", type=input.bool, defval=true)
var weekH=0.0
var pweekH=0.0
[bi,t,hi] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", [bar_index,time,high], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

d=dayofweek(t)
if bi>bi[1]
    if d==6
        pweekH:=weekH
        weekH:=hi
    else if  weekH<hi
        weekH:=hi
plot(plotWH ? pweekH : na, title = "Weekly High" , color = weekHLColor, style = plot.style_linebr, linewidth =2)
```