# Weekly expiry day change and pivot levels

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking for Banknifty Index pivots which is usually weekly expiry on every Wednesday but last week expiry(monthly expiry) will be on last Thursday of the month. somehow I got pivot levels for Wednesday expires but for Thursday (monthly) expiry desired results are not coming i.e the pivot lines are extended until next Wednesday which is omitting a week. I copied some code from below threads.
[Get the last trading day of the month (in Pine Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640158/get-the-last-trading-day-of-the-month-in-pine-script)
[Pinescript week starting from Friday to Thursday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127886/pinescript-week-starting-from-friday-to-thursday)

My code is given below.

```
    //@version=5
indicator('Experimental', overlay=true)
weekdayExpiry = input.int(defval = 5, title="Expiry Day", options=[5], tooltip = "3-Monday, 4-Tuesday, 5-Wednesday, 6-Thursday, 7-Friday")
var pivotTFHigh = 0.00
var pivotTFLow = 0.00
var pivotTFClose = 0.00
var weekH = 0.0
var pweekH = 0.0
var weekL = 0.0
f_is_leap_year() =>
    if ((year % 4) != 0)
        false
    else if ((year % 100) != 0)
        true
    else if ((year % 400) == 0)
        true
    else
        false
f_get_last_day() =>
    if (month == 1) or (month == 3) or (month == 5) or (month == 7) or (month == 8) or (month == 10) or (month == 12)
        31
    else if (month == 4) or (month == 6) or (month == 9) or (month == 11)
        30
    else 
        f_is_leap_year() ? 29 : 28  // February
Monthly_Expiry = dayofmonth > f_get_last_day() - 7 and dayofweek == 5
    
[bi, t, hi] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [bar_index, time, high], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
[li, ti, lo] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [bar_index, time, low], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
[ci, tc, pweekCL] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [bar_index, time, close], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

d = dayofweek(t)
if Monthly_Expiry
    weekdayExpiry1 = weekdayExpiry + 1
    if bi > bi[1] 
        if d == weekdayExpiry1
            pivotTFHigh := weekH
            weekH := hi
            weekH
            weekdayExpiry1 := weekdayExpiry
            pivotTFClose := pweekCL[1]
        else if weekH < hi
            weekH := hi
            weekH        
else if bi > bi[1] 
    if d == weekdayExpiry
        pivotTFHigh := weekH
        weekH := hi
        weekH
        pivotTFClose := pweekCL[1]
    else if weekH < hi
        weekH := hi
        weekH  
            
da = dayofweek(t)
if Monthly_Expiry
    weekdayExpiry1 = weekdayExpiry + 1
    if li > li[1] 
        if da == weekdayExpiry1
            pivotTFLow := weekL
            weekL := lo
            weekL
            weekdayExpiry1 := weekdayExpiry
        else if weekL > lo
            weekL := lo
            weekL        
else if li > li[1] 
    if da == weekdayExpiry
        pivotTFLow := weekL
        weekL := lo
        weekL
    else if weekL > lo
        weekL := lo
        weekL
        
// Pivot Calculations

pLevel = (pivotTFHigh + pivotTFLow + pivotTFClose) / 3
bcLevel = (pivotTFHigh + pivotTFLow) / 2
tcLevel = 2 * pLevel - bcLevel
pLevelrange = pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow
r1 = pLevel * 2 - pivotTFLow
s1 = pLevel * 2 - pivotTFHigh
r2 = pLevel + 1 * (pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow)
s2 = pLevel - 1 * (pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow)
r3 = pLevel * 2 + (pivotTFHigh - 2 * pivotTFLow)
s3 = pLevel * 2 - (2 * pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow)
r4 = pLevel * 3 + (pivotTFHigh - 3 * pivotTFLow)
s4 = pLevel * 3 - (3 * pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow)
r5 = pLevel * 4 + (pivotTFHigh - 4 * pivotTFLow)
s5 = pLevel * 4 - (4 * pivotTFHigh - pivotTFLow)

// Create series which will hold line and label ids as they are created.
var line pLine = na
var line bcLine = na
var line tcLine = na
var line r1Line = na
var line r2Line = na
var line r3Line = na
var line r4Line = na
var line r5Line = na
var line s1Line = na
var line s2Line = na
var line s3Line = na
var line s4Line = na
var line s5Line = na
var line HiLine = na
var line CLine = na
var line LLine = na
// var line OLine = na
var label pLbl2 = na
var label HLbl2 = na
var label CLbl2 = na
var label LLbl2 = na
// var label OLbl2 = na
line.set_color (pLine, color.lime)
line.set_color (bcLine, color.lime)
line.set_color (tcLine, color.lime)
line.set_color(HiLine, color.red)
line.set_color(CLine, color.black)
line.set_color(LLine, color.green)
// line.set_color(OLine, color.orange)
label.set_color(pLbl2, color.lime)
label.set_color(HLbl2, color.red)
label.set_color(CLbl2, color.black)
label.set_color(LLbl2, color.green)
// label.set_color(OLbl2, color.orange)

if pLevel[1] != pLevel
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(bcLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(tcLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(HiLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(CLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(LLine, bar_index)
    // line.set_x2(OLine, bar_index)
    
    pLine := line.new(bar_index, pLevel, bar_index, pLevel, width = 3, extend=extend.none)
    bcLine := line.new(bar_index, bcLevel, bar_index, bcLevel, width = 2, extend=extend.none)
    tcLine := line.new(bar_index, tcLevel, bar_index, tcLevel, width = 2, extend=extend.none)
    HiLine := line.new(bar_index, pivotTFHigh, bar_index, pivotTFHigh, width = 3, extend=extend.none)
    CLine := line.new(bar_index, pivotTFClose, bar_index, pivotTFClose, width = 3, extend=extend.none)
    LLine := line.new(bar_index, pivotTFLow, bar_index, pivotTFLow, width = 3, extend=extend.none)
    r1Line := line.new(bar_index, r1, bar_index, r1, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    r2Line := line.new(bar_index, r2, bar_index, r2, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    r3Line := line.new(bar_index, r3, bar_index, r3, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    r4Line := line.new(bar_index, r4, bar_index, r4, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    r5Line := line.new(bar_index, r5, bar_index, r5, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    s1Line := line.new(bar_index, s1, bar_index, s1, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    s2Line := line.new(bar_index, s2, bar_index, s2, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    s3Line := line.new(bar_index, s3, bar_index, s3, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    s4Line := line.new(bar_index, s4, bar_index, s4, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    s5Line := line.new(bar_index, s5, bar_index, s5, width=2, extend=extend.none, color = color.teal)
    // OLine := line.new(bar_index, open1, bar_index, open1, width = 3)

    pLbl2 := label.new(bar_index, pLevel, text = "PW PP " + str.tostring(pLevel, "#.##"), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small, style=label.style_label_left)
    HLbl2 := label.new(bar_index, pivotTFHigh, text = "PW High " + str.tostring(pivotTFHigh, "#.##"), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small, style=label.style_label_left)
    CLbl2  := label.new(bar_index, pivotTFClose, text = "PW Close " + str.tostring(pivotTFClose, "#.##"), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small, style=label.style_label_left)
    LLbl2 := label.new(bar_index, pivotTFLow, text = "PW Low " + str.tostring(pivotTFLow, "#.##"), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small, style=label.style_label_left)
    // OLbl2 := label.new(bar_index, open1, text = "Monthly Open " + str.tostring(open1, "#.##"), textcolor = color.white, size = size.small, style=label.style_label_left)

if not na(HiLine) and line.get_x2(HiLine) != bar_index
    line.set_x2(pLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(bcLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(tcLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(HiLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(CLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(LLine, bar_index + 3)
    // line.set_x2(OLine, bar_index + 3)
    line.set_x2(r1Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(r2Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(r3Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(r4Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(r5Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(s1Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(s2Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(s3Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(s4Line, bar_index + 1)
    line.set_x2(s5Line, bar_index + 1)
    label.set_x(pLbl2, bar_index + 3)
    label.set_x(HLbl2, bar_index + 3)
    label.set_x(CLbl2, bar_index + 3)
    label.set_x(LLbl2, bar_index + 3)
    // label.set_x(OLbl2, bar_index + 3)
```